# How to place one region below the other while reducing the width in drupal 7?

Tags: theming

Currently, I am creating a single page responsive website in Drupal 7. After making the page responsive, I added a block with two regions: *about us* and *ethics* side by side that is in two columns. When reducing the browser width, the content still remains in two columns!!! I want the region *about us* to be below *ethics*, but I am not aware how to do it!! Can anyone guide me with the aforestated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use float:left on both elements with fixed widths that will automatically stack when the page width is reduced enough.

Or use a CSS media query to make the regions adapt once a certain screen width is reached.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="region1">CONTENT1</div>
    <div class="region2">CONTENT2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {width:100%}
.region1 {width:50%}
.region2 {width:50%}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.region1 {width:100%}
.region2 {width:100%}


}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)